# Get data-key of a tag when clicked where many classes exists

Tags: javascript, onclick, alert

I want to get the innerHTML of a div when clicked 
where all the class names are the same.

It works for **A** text, but it doesn't work when S or D is clicked.

```
<div class="keys">
     <div data-key="65" class="key">
      <kbd>A</kbd>
      <span class="sound">clap</span>
    </div>

    <div data-key="83" class="key">
      <kbd>S</kbd>
      <span class="sound">hihat</span>
    </div>

    <div data-key="68" class="key">
      <kbd>D</kbd>
      <span class="sound">kick</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript code

```
var x = document.querySelector('.key');
x.addEventListener('click', popUp);

function popUp(e) {
    alert(e.target.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: before reading the answers, read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and see if you can figure out where you went wrong

Comment: Thanks. querySelector() selects only the first element with the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll` instead `querySelector` in combination with `Array.from` method.

Since `querySelectorAll()` *returns* a *NodeList*, you have to attach a `click` event *handler* for every item.

```js
var x = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.key')).forEach(function(item){
   item.addEventListener('click', popUp);
});

function popUp(e) {
    alert(e.target.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div class="keys">
     <div data-key="65" class="key">
      <kbd>A</kbd>
      <span class="sound">clap</span>
    </div>

    <div data-key="83" class="key">
      <kbd>S</kbd>
      <span class="sound">hihat</span>
    </div>

    <div data-key="68" class="key">
      <kbd>D</kbd>
      <span class="sound">kick</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either add an event listener to each `.key` element:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.key').forEach(key => {
  key.addEventListener('click', () => console.log(key.innerHTML));
});
```

```html
<div class="keys">
     <div data-key="65" class="key">
      <kbd>A</kbd>
      <span class="sound">clap</span>
    </div>

    <div data-key="83" class="key">
      <kbd>S</kbd>
      <span class="sound">hihat</span>
    </div>

    <div data-key="68" class="key">
      <kbd>D</kbd>
      <span class="sound">kick</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or, rather than adding a listener for every `key`, it would probably be more elegant to use only a *single* listener to the `.keys` container, via event delegation, and find the `closest` `.key` from the clicked element:

```js
document.querySelector('.keys').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const key = e.target.closest('.key');
  console.log(key.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<div class="keys">
  <div data-key="65" class="key">
    <kbd>A</kbd>
    <span class="sound">clap</span>
  </div>

  <div data-key="83" class="key">
    <kbd>S</kbd>
    <span class="sound">hihat</span>
  </div>

  <div data-key="68" class="key">
    <kbd>D</kbd>
    <span class="sound">kick</span>
  </div>
</div>
```